# How to convert a date stored as string in MongoDB to ISODate?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection in which each document has a time field with value stored as similar to "21-Dec-2017".
I want to convert this to ISODate using projection.
My Query:

```
db.getCollection('orders').aggregate([{

        $project:{time : {$add : new Date("$time")}}
        }])
```

But this is returning me  ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z") always.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this,

```
db.getCollection('orders').aggregate([{
            $project: {
                time: {
                    $dateToString: {
                        format: "%d-%m-%G",
                        date: new Date("$time")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ])
```

there is no any string function to get months name eg.Jan,Feb..Dec.
but you can refer https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/
to more information.

Comment: $dateToString is introduced in mongodb version 3.6.Unfortunately we are using older version,so this is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in this `ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z")` format.

you should store date in `ISO` format but change format on client side according to you.

Basically you want to show date in `dd/mm/yy` format.

You can use http://momentjs.com/  to show date according to you.